# Two conditions in one if statement

Tags: angular

How to check both conditions at the same time in one if statement in angular 9+

I need to satisfy both conditions for my html element.

i have tried `<div *ngIf="(params.folder!= 'folder1') || (params.folder!= 'folder2')">`

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: condition not working if i give them together.it will work when i given one at a time!

Comment: Well, I think you can get rid of the brackets in total or put the two conditions in yet another set of brackets. But in general, it should work the way you did it.

Comment: If you want the statement to be true if the `folder` is not `folder1` AND `folder2`, try `(params.folder!= 'folder1') && (params.folder!= 'folder2')` or `!((params.folder=== 'folder1') || (params.folder === 'folder2'))`

Comment: [In order for a question to be answered, it must specify what exactly is wrong. Stating simply that “it doesn’t work” is not sufficient.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz, I did answer that, and someone downvoted me.

Comment: I think the problem you have is not the syntax but rather the understanding of the logical combination you need to apply to your two conditions as also stated by e.g.  @HarunYilmaz

Comment: yes when i put && instead of || it works! Thanks!

Comment: @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero Usually, 'try this' type of answers can get downvotes unless they have the explanation about why to try it. You can try to add explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that didn't work, try this:

```
<div *ngIf="((params.folder!= 'folder1') && (params.folder!= 'folder2'))">
```

Comment: You only have to edit your question, and say that you wanted to happen both conditions at the same time, and probably people undownvote it. As long as you do not edit it, the downvote cannot be removed.